# ungroup SUM and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sum

I know how to do a `SUM` in MySQL but how add a column like this (ungroup the group ?)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `price` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `price`)
VALUES
    (1,10),
    (1, 10),
    (2, 20),
    (2, 20),
    (3, 30),
    (3, 31)
;
```

ID would be think like a 'category ID'.
I want this :

```
ID    price    sum
--------------------
 1     10      20 <- or nothing if it's not to hard
 1     10      20
 2     20      40 
 2     20      40
 3     30      61
 3     31      61
```

Not this :

```
ID    price    sum
--------------------
 1     10      20
 2     20      40
 3     30      61
```

sql :

```
SELECT id, SUM(price)FROM Table1 GROUP BY id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34fbe/1

Comment: you mean get the sum for the group, then show the original records that produced that sum?

Comment: So you provided a correct and an incorrect query result. Where is the table structure, the data and where are the queries?

Comment: @GolezTrol why do you need queries ? I put a sqlfiddle (few minutes after the post)…

Comment: Well that wasn't there when I commented. Besides, (from [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) "*If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. **Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time**."*

Comment: I teach HTML and CSS in an art and design school, students's questions are not always clear but I know what they want to do…
I dont have code to include because the project is now with a lots of table and column… so I make a "clear" sample… But it's ok I will edit my post to be more useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery:

```
select t.*, tt.sumprice
from table1 t join
     (select id, sum(price) as sumprice
      from table1 t
      group by id
     ) tt
     on t.id = tt.id;
```

Comment: @benoît `table` is used as a placeholder for your real table, of course :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34fbe/7

Comment: @Gordon Is there a way we can achieve the same result without using sub-queries?

Comment: @mrudult . . . If you have a specific question, you should ask it as a question, not a comment.  Include sample data, desired results, and an explanation of why you don't want a subquery.

Comment: I just want to know if the **exact same question** can be solved with using a sub-query? If yes, then how?